# HorizontalScrollView don't works with buttons

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

For some reasons, when I start adding buttons to  I received error.

I found in web, what someone changed android version and it's helped to him, I changed android version from 25 to 19, but this not helped to me.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:id="@+id/button1" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3"
    android:id="@+id/button3" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="4"
    android:id="@+id/button4" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Need to show buttons, but I received an error

Indirect rendering enabled
Bridge [resources.resolve] Couldn't resolve resource @string/abc_action_bar_home_description
Failed to process message Load
mono.android.DesignerException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at mono.android.DesignerException.fromThrowable(DesignerException.java:54)
    at mono.android.DesignerSession.checkRenderResultForError(DesignerSession.java:215)
    at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:302)
    at mono.android.DesignerSession.processMessage(DesignerSession.java:665)
    at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
    at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child
    at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.addView(HorizontalScrollView.java:251)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:867)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:866)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:327)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:386)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:270)
    at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:289)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see the error log: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child`, so you can add a container to wrap these Buttons,e.g. a `LinearLayout`,  just as follows:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:id="@+id/button1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3"
            android:id="@+id/button3" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4"
            android:id="@+id/button4" />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

The effect is:[image]

Comment: Glad to help.Happy coding.